# Binomial Expansion of $x^n$ coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Given

$$(1-\frac{x}{10})^{-3}=1+\frac{3}{10}x+\frac{3}{50}x^2+\frac{1}{100}x^3+\frac{3}{2000}x^4+\cdots$$

Show that the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1-\frac{x}{10})^{-3}$ is $\frac{1}{2}(n+1)(n+2)\frac{1}{10^n}$.

After evaluating a few terms, it is evident the statement is true. However, I am struggling to prove this rigorously. Induction seems unnecessarily complicated so I think a proof by deduction would be best where you prove for a general coefficient in the binomial expansion of $(1-\frac{x}{10})^{-3}$, though the cancellations become quite confusing with so many negatives etc..

Thanks

I have used the formula

$(1+x)^n = 1 +nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2 +\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+...+$

which gives for $x^n$ coefficient in the binomial expansion of $(1-\frac{x}{10})^{-3}$

$\frac{(-3)(-4)(-5)...(-3-(n-2))(-3-(n-1))}{n(n-1)(n-2)...3\times2\times1}(-\frac{1}{10}x)^n)$

I am not sure how to simplify this properly, but I want to specifically used this formula??

Given

$(1+x)^k = 1 +kx + \frac{k(k-1)}{2!}x^2 +\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}x^3+...+$

$= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n+1)}{n!}x^n$

$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n+1)(k-n)(k-n-1)...2\times1}{n!(k-n)(k-n-1)...2\times1}x^n$

$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}x^n$

$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {k \choose n}x^n$

Which links the two general results together.

Therefore the coefficient of $x^n$ for the expansion of $(1-\frac{x}{10})^{-3}$ is

${-3\choose n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) gives $$(1 - \frac{x}{10})^{-3} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \binom{3 +n-1}{n} \frac{1}{10^n} x^n = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \binom{n+2}{2}\frac{1}{10^n} x^n\ $$
which is exactly what you have.

---

EDIT:  Here's a calculation \begin{align*}
\binom{-3}{n}(-1)^n &= \frac{(-3)(-4)\cdots(-3 - (n-1))}{n!}(-1)^n \\
&=\frac{3\cdot 4 \cdots (n+2)}{n!} \\
&=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm not sure how you got ${-3 \choose n } = {{3 + n -1} \choose n}$? I have included my workings in my edited post but I am stuck at this point

Comment: You're missing a $(-1)^n$; I included the calculation in an edit